# Java - Always 0?

Tags: java, math, coordinates, calculator

i have a normal Java code, that just calculate a x-coordinate, but it is just 0;

```
private static final int startX = (Level.WIDTH / 2) - (Block.LENGTH * (Level.COLUMNS / 2));
```

At the time of calculating:

```
Level.WIDTH = 1000;
Block.LENGTH = 41;
Level.COLUMNS = 12;
```

Accord my calculation it must be 254, but its always 0.
Did anybody know my error?

Comment: Where did you set the Level.WIDTH, Block.LENGTH and Level.COLUMNS?

Comment: How are these values declared?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
private static final int startX = (Level.WIDTH / 2) - (Block.LENGTH * (Level.COLUMNS / 2));
```

This variable is evaluated once when the class it belongs to is initialized. At the time that happens, the variables it depends on (`Level.WIDTH`, `Block.LENGTH`, `Level.COLUMNS`) are probably still containing 0.

When declaring a final variable whose value depends on the value of other variables, those variables should also be final and be initialized before the variable that depends on them.

It's not mandatory, but your code won't make much sense otherwise, since changing, for example, the value of `Level.COLUMNS` after `startX` was initialized won't change the value of `startX`, so it will seem to hold an inconsistent value.

Comment: But i watched with the debugger and the other variables still have the values at this time

Comment: @Marvin What do you mean by `at this time`? startX is static, so it will be initialized when the class it belongs to is initialized. I don't know where the other variables are located and when they are initialized, but they are probably initialized later.

Comment: The other variables are in diffrent classes but final and static too.

Comment: ohhh iam so sorry, i just changed the other variables form 0 to diffrent values and forgot to save this. Iam so sorry, shame on me :/

Comment: @Marvin Happens to everyone :)